# What IP addresses does StarCraft 2 connect to?

Tags: starcraft-2, technical-issues

Is there a published list somewhere of all the IPs of servers Starcraft 2 would need to connect to? I can only open my outgoing ports to certain IPs or to ranges of them, so for now I'm stuck with analysing firewall logs again and again to find various IPs I tried connecting to.

Comment: Why block outgoing traffic ? You should only block incoming traffic.

Comment: @Michael: I wish I knew.

Comment: Don't suppose you can open your ports to the IP range 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255? ;)

Comment: I asked Blizzard support, in case you're wondering, and their reply is they can't disclose that information.

Comment: I'd have expected a portion of the communication at least is p2p?

Comment: @TZHX: That does apply for the downloader, and for voice chat. But the game is definitely playable with 0 incoming ports meaning no p2p transmissions.

Comment: well, unless you have a strangely configured firewall, it's not normally necessary to specifically open ports on a router.

Comment: Why are you trying to block outgoing traffic? In the default situation StarCraft II should just work. Even on a ZyXEL ZyWall it does work so I don't understand why it wouldn't in your case... Can you specify more information about your router?

Answer (score 2):

I've asked Blizzard support and they're claiming it's confidential information and they can't publish that. As such, I will not include my findings here, but I will tell you this: after a few searches related to the IPs my computer was accessing I found that the CDN which runs SC2 has a specific range of IPs that all SC2 servers seem to use. This range has a subnet mask of `255.255.224.0`. The login servers have a different address with subnet mask `255.255.255.0`.

*Update*: I just tried these ips and its still not enough. Now I have to wait for my sysadmin to see what's being blocked *yet again*...

Comment: Hi, configurator! Might I suggest that you conclude this question by simply accepting your current answer on the confidentiality of this information and how it may not be published, instead of updating this with any future findings? Our [content policy](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/legal/content-policy) forbids illegal activity, and I strongly recommend we not test the murky depths of confidentiality law with how far one can stretch this. "It is confidential and cannot be published" is a valid solution to the posited question "Is there a published list of IPs".

Comment: Server IPs to which your PC connects are not and cannot be confidential information. 

If Blizzard employees do not wish to disclose that information it is understandable, but disclosing those addresses CAN NOT be illegal.

Comment: Indeed, I feel the same way as Mavrik. I won't publish the IPs which Blizzard wish to remain somewhat secret, though - if anybody wants them he can ask me.

Comment: I will admit to some ignorance of the full scale of law with regards to this issue. I'm sorry if I came off as silencing, but my main intention is just to keep everyone here safe - and that includes keeping not just the site but individual users such as you out of any sort of legal trouble's way. Perhaps overly precautious, but as they say it's better to be safe than sorry.

Comment: Blizzard may choose not to disclose the list of IP addresses if they want to, but I don't see how publishing a list you determined through *your own research* could **possibly** be considered illegal.

Answer (score 2):

These might help, picked out of my own router connection table while participating in SEA based matches then checked against http://www.robtex.com to identify who owns the range.

SEA Battle.net ranges

202.9.66.0/23

12.129.254.0/24

12.129.255.0/24

12.129.206.0/24

As Brant said, publishing a list of addresses is not illegal, the information is freely available just that Blizzard choose not to reveal it willingly. Same as anyone can work out what IP address their favorite WoW server is, but blizzard won't tell you.